# AuthorizationError.USER_PERMISSION_DENIED when testing against test MCC account (Creating Account)

Tags: java, google-ads-api

I'm trying to test the AdWords API to learn about its features.
I couldn't figure out why I keep getting AuthorizationError.USER_PERMISSION_DENIED error.

For example, I try to run CreateAccount.java in Java client library example provided from AdWords.

Here are my steps:
1. I created a production MCC account and then get a "Developer Token"
2. I created a test MCC account and then get a new "Client ID" and "Client Secret" from console. From this I got the "Refresh Token"
I put the "Developer Token" (from step #1 above), "Client ID" and "Client Secret" to ads.properties.
3. For "user agent" values in ads.properties, I put in the name of the "Project ID".
4. And for the "client customer id" values in ads.properties, I put the test MCC account customer ID.
5. Then I try to run this below and got the AuthorizationError.USER_PERMISSION_DENIED error.

I'm wondering if there's any step I'm missing or doing wrong.
Thank you in advance for the help.

Below is the code I'm trying to run. The exception is thrown on this line:

```
ManagedCustomerReturnValue result = managedCustomerService.mutate(operations);
```

And here's the complete snippet (from the AdWords code sample)

```
// Generate a refreshable OAuth2 credential similar to a ClientLogin token
// and can be used in place of a service account.
Credential oAuth2Credential = new OfflineCredentials.Builder()
    .forApi(Api.ADWORDS)
    .fromFile()
    .build()
    .generateCredential();


// Construct an AdWordsSession.
AdWordsSession session = new AdWordsSession.Builder()
    .fromFile()
    .withOAuth2Credential(oAuth2Credential)
    .build();


AdWordsServices adWordsServices = new AdWordsServices();

// Get the CampaignService.
ManagedCustomerServiceInterface managedCustomerService =
    adWordsServices.get(session, ManagedCustomerServiceInterface.class);


// Create account.
ManagedCustomer customer = new ManagedCustomer();
customer.setName("Customer created with ManagedCustomerService on " + new DateTime());
customer.setCurrencyCode("EUR");
customer.setDateTimeZone("Europe/London");


// Create operations.
ManagedCustomerOperation operation = new ManagedCustomerOperation();
operation.setOperand(customer);
operation.setOperator(Operator.ADD);


ManagedCustomerOperation[] operations = new ManagedCustomerOperation[ {operation};


// Add account.
ManagedCustomerReturnValue result = managedCustomerService.mutate(operations);


// Display accounts.
for (ManagedCustomer customerResult : result.getValue()) {
  System.out.println("Account with customer ID \"" + customerResult.getCustomerId()
      + "\" was created.");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have followed these steps :

1] Created one app on Google Developer Console, And Got these values for ads.properties :
api.adwords.clientId and api.adwords.clientSecret

2] Then you create Production MCC Account where you got developerToken. Put that into ads.properties.

3] Then created MCC test Account where you have got main mcc accounts adwords id, you may have put it into ads.properties.

4] Then you get refresh Token using running GetRefreshToken.java from sample provided by google team.(Recheck here that after running GetRefreshToken.java you post url got on java output console to browser and given permission to this app by logging in into your test mcc gmail account. Then there you get some string in browser window. Copy that string as input to the java output console and press enter. At this stage you will get real refreshToken as output in java output console copy that to your ads.properties).

5] After setting this set useragent to some random string.

6] Then run the java program  CreateAccount.java from samples provided by google team.

7] This should work.

Most of the time people do mistake at generating refreshToken follow process step by step for "GetRefreshToken.java".

Comment: Thanks ! It works. I miss this part: "..given permission to this app by logging in into your test mcc gmail account ..". I found out I login using the prod mcc gmail account.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you gave permission with the correct MMC.
If you want to view test client data, you have to copy the link generated by GetRefreshToken while you're logged whit TEST MCC. If you want to view prod. client data, you copy the link generated by GetRefreshToken while you're logged whit the prod. MCC.

Here the complete doc:
    https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/test-accounts